# why grep does not print the entire line?

Tags: bash, grep, ls

When I enter `ls` command I get the below output.

```
-$ ls
aNode  ANode  bNode  BNode  cNode  CNode  DUMP  file1  hello.txt  TEST.txt
-$
```

As seen, above output is `one` line which has `filenames` separeted by `spaces`.

Next when I use `grep` to find a match.

I was expecting that if a match is found then the entire line will be printed.

But, on the contrary, grep only prints the match but not the entire line containing the match. Please see below.

```
-$ ls | grep 'aNode'
aNode
-$
```

Why is this happening ? Why is `grep`  not printing the entire line ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls` has different output formats and displays things differently if it's writing to a terminal instead of a pipe.  When writing to a pipe it writes just one entry per line, so `grep` can work on each listing individually.

So when you do that `grep` you are getting a different output from `ls` than when you just run `ls` and print to the screen.

You can see the same affect that `grep` is experiencing if you do

```
ls | cat
```

which will display all the entries, one per line.